# How to add Leaflet extensions (marker, basemap, geocoder, ...) to Django Leaflet-Map-Widget Form?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, leaflet

I set up a Django-Project with a Leaflet Map. Basically I want to fill some Input fields, draw a line on the map and then save it to admin.

I created a model with different input fields.
I created a form with the same fields and a "widgets = {'geom': LeafletWidget()}".

In my template and view I am able to fill the input fields and draw a line on the map and then save it to django-admin/database. So far so good.

BUT now I want to add more layers to the map. And I want to add some extensions like markers, geocoder for address search or layer control options.

In my template I loaded the map like this: `{{form.geom}}`

After that I tried to add the extensions like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function map_init_basic (map, options) {

        L.marker([51.1963, 14.3947]).addTo(map);
}
```

...

but the marker is not added to the map. If I change "map" to "id_geom-map" (as referred to in the online view) same result. Not added.

I am able to set up the map manually (not a part of the form) like this at the end of the template:

```
{% leaflet_map "map" callback="window.map_init_basic" %}
```

... and then I can add whatever layer or extensions I want (with the same code as above). But then the drawn feature on the new map is not part of the original form and therefore not saved to django-admin.

So how do I add the extensions to make them show in the map as a part of the form?

I already spent a lot of time on this topic so any help would be highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to add the Leaflet Geocoder (https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder) to my GeoDjango project, but I haven't been able to add extra overlays or base layers to the map.

To get the geocoder to work I added a LEAFLET_CONFIG section to settings.py:

```
 LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
     'PLUGINS': {
         'geocoder': {
         'css': ['https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css'],
         'js': ['https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js'],
         }
      }
 }
```

Then in my template's  section I load the leaflet stuff:

```
 {% load leaflet_tags %}
 {% leaflet_css plugins="forms, geocoder" %}
 {% leaflet_js plugins="forms, geocoder" %}
```

And in the body I have a snippet of Javascript to load the geocoder:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("map:init", function(e) {
            var detail = e.detail;
            L.Control.geocoder().addTo(detail.map);
        }, false
    ); //end of window.addEventListener

</script>
```

This page from the django-leaflet documentation was very helpful:  https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html#